# Imprimir divs separadas mas com o mesmo id

Tags: php, javascript, html, impressão

Gostaria de um script para imprimir uma div separada da outra que tem o mesmo id ex.:

```
<div id="print">
<p>Imprimir este conteúdo separado das outras div</p>
<input type="buttom" value="Imprimir">
</div>

<div id="print">
<p>Imprimir este conteúdo separado das outras div</p>
<input type="buttom" value="Imprimir">
</div>

<div id="print">
<p>Imprimir este conteúdo separado das outras div</p>
<input type="buttom" value="Imprimir">
</div>
```

Comment: Os `ids` devem ser único por página... Considere fazer um [tour] e adequar sua questão segundo explicado na [help]. Boa Sorte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se da certo:

```
        <script>
function imprimir(mesmo){
    var conteudo = mesmo.parentElement.innerHTML,
        tela_impressao = window.open('about:blank');

    tela_impressao.document.write(conteudo);
    tela_impressao.window.print();
    tela_impressao.window.close();
}
</script>

<div id="print">
<p>Imprimir este conteúdo separado das outras div</p>
<input type="button" value="Imprimir" onclick="imprimir(this);">
</div>

<div id="print">
<p>Imprimir este conteúdo separado das outras div</p>
<input type="buttom" value="Imprimir" onclick="imprimir(this);">
</div>

<div id="print">
<p>Imprimir este conteúdo separado das outras div</p>
<input type="buttom" value="Imprimir" onclick="imprimir(this);">
</div>
```

Comment: Acho que esse vai testei ele sozinho funcionou! Vou jogar na aplicação minha e te aviso perai...

Comment: PERFEITOOOOO!!!! FUNCIONOU MEU AMIGO! MUITO OBRIGADO!  NOTA 10!

Comment: Coloca um joinha então na minha reposta fazendo favor...

Comment: Pronto! Valeuu!